# Call a command, wait, then execute another command

Tags: xargs, inotify

This feels like a situation where I need to watch a stream (stdin), if a line comes in, wait a moment, then fire the command and wait some more.

Using a tool like pyinotify or fswatch, we can watch a folder for changes and when one is found, echo it out.

`fswatch --recursive --latency 2 src/ | xargs make build`

or

`pyinotify -r -a -e IN_CLOSE_WRITE -c 'make build' src/`

In my case, I am trying to figure out how to call `make build` whenever a file changes.  While the above tools do work, they can end up calling `make build` a lot and in rapid succession.  Each tool works a little bit differently, but the end result is the same (make is getting called too much)

I need all of the gyrating to stop, 1 second to elapse, and then invoke make just one time.

Is there some unix way to batch up the commands and then invoke make?  Something like this:

`fswatch --recursive src/ | aggregate_and_wait --delay 1second | make build`

Comment: Write a script that runs the build with a `sleep 1` up at the top somewhere.  Have your `fswatch` or `pyinotify` call that script.

Comment: If we have 5 lines come in on the stream, this approach will still fire the command 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

Have your canary (the process looking for changes) write a state file at e. g. `/var/run/build-needed`.

Set up a cron job to run every minute (or every five minutes, or whatever frequency you think is apt for your use-case) your automated build script that will:

- check for `/var/run/build-needed`, and if it is not newer than `/var/run/last-build`, abort.
- check for `/var/run/build-in-progress` and, if it is present, abort.
- create `/var/run/build/in-progress`
- execute the build.
- remove `/var/run/in-progress` and `touch` `/var/run/last-build`.

An example skeleton implementation:

The canary process:

```
pyinotify -r -a -e IN_CLOSE_WRITE -c 'touch /var/run/build-needed' src/
```

The `cron` job:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/autobuilder.sh
```

The builder script:

```
#!/bin/bash
canaryfile="/var/run/build-needed"
lastbuild="/var/run/last-build"
inprogress="/var/run/build-in-progress"
needbuild="no"
if [[ -f "$canaryfile" ]]; then
    if [[ -f "$lastbuild" ]] && [[ "$canaryfile" -nt "$lastbuild" ]]; then
        needbuild="yes"
    elif ! [[ -f "$lastbuild" ]]; then
        needbuild="yes"
    fi
fi
if ! [[ -f "$inprogress" && "yes" == "$needbuild" ]]; then
    cd /path/to/src
    touch "$inprogress"
    if make build; then
        rm "$inprogress"
        touch "$lastbuild"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: I hate to say it, but this is too complex for what I'm trying to do.  I'm actually using a Makefile, so I'm looking for something rather tight, small, minimal.  A cron tab entry is too heavy.  Overall, however, the notion of a canary file makes sense.  How can something like that be done in just 2-3 lines of bash?

Comment: This pair of commands works, but is there a way to invoke them at the same time and then when I Ctrl+C, they both quit?
 `@fswatch --recursive src/ | xargs -I{} touch build-canary;`

 `@while inotifywait -e close_write build-canary; do sleep 3 && make build; done`

Comment: It depends on how robust you want it to be.  This example for instance also makes sure you don't start one build while another is going, which is a good idea, but not one mentioned in your original question.